# Something like fast.com for intranet?

Tags: networking, performance-analysis

Does anybody know a tool like https://fast.com or https://speedtest.net that can be deployed inside an intranet. I know about various benchmarking tools like iperf, but I'd like to have something that can be run by regular users from a browser.

Comment: I think, actually you only need some client-side javascript and a static http(s) hosting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it!

https://librespeed.org/ is a free and OpenSource speed test and the backend is very simplistic (like https://github.com/saudiqbal/speed-test-openwrt ). I ended up rewriting it a bit in C for OpenWrt.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't mention it has be free, Speedtest actually provides exactly what you want: https://www.ookla.com/speedtest-custom

For a free very basic (only time based) solution, https://www.raditha.com/blog/archives/1791.html offered a small PHP test, assuming your Intranet allows PHP. But they didn't make it possible to run directly, so I **modified** to do so. Can you try it? If it doesn't work like you want, you can post it on https://stackoverflow.com to ask for further development (if you do, please link here to the question there):

```
<?php
$s="0";
for($i = 0 ; $i < 16; $i++)
    $s .= $s;
$date_start = time();
for($i = 0 ; $i < 2048; $i++)
        echo $s . nl2br("\n");
$date_end = time();
echo nl2br('Started at ' . date('r', $date_start) . '
Ended at ' . date('r', $date_end) . '
Took ' . date_diff(new DateTime("@$date_start"), new DateTime("@$date_end"))->format('%hh %im %ss'));
?>
```

Comment: Yes, a custom speedtest would have been awesome, but $2k a year is above my budget. I can deploy whatever I can (within reasons) though.

Comment: So please consider marking my answer as accepted, then if the script above isn't good enough, copy it to Stackoverflow and ask to take it further.